# YTickLabel will be shown with some specified value (not show all) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, colormap

I have code and the result as below:

```
%% How to plot each matrix in a cell in 3d plot(1 matrix with 1 color) ?
% Generate Sample data cell A(1x10 cell array)
clear; clc;
A = cell(1,10); % cell A(1x10 cell array)
for kk = 1:numel(A)
  z = 10*rand()+(0:pi/50:10*rand()*pi)';
  x = 10*rand()*sin(z);
  y = 10*rand()*cos(z);
  A{kk} = [x,y,z];
end  
A_6 = A(1:6);        % generate a cell with the first 6 matrices in "A" cell array 
                     % The numer "6" can be changed to be any number which you want to plot them by colormap                      
newA = vertcat(A_6{:});                   %Concatenating all matrices inside A vertically
numcolors = numel(A_6);                   %Number of matrices equals number of colors
colourRGB = hsv(numcolors);             %Generating colours to be used using hsv colormap
colourtimes = cellfun(@(x) size(x,1),A_6);%Determining num of times each colour will be used
colourind = zeros(size(newA,1),1);      %Zero matrix with length equals num of points
colourind([1 cumsum(colourtimes(1:end-1))+1]) = 1;
colourind = cumsum(colourind);          %Linear indices of colours for newA
scatter3(newA(:,1), newA(:,2), newA(:,3), [], colourRGB(colourind,:),'filled');
%if you want to specify the size of the circles, use the following line instead:
% scatter3(newA(:,1), newA(:,2), newA(:,3), colourind , colourRGB(colourind,:),'filled');
grid on;
view(3);                                %view in 3d plane 
colormap(colourRGB);                    %using the custom colormap of the colors we used
%Adjusting the position of the colorbar ticks
caxis([1 numcolors]);
colorbar('YTick',[1+0.5*(numcolors-1)/numcolors:(numcolors-1)/numcolors:numcolors],'YTickLabel', num2str([1:numcolors]'), 'YLim', [1 numcolors]);
```

I have the image like this:
[image]

How can I shown "YTickLabel" with some specified value (not show all) as below figure?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the code from your comment to the previous answer:

```
h = colorbar('YTick',[1:numcolors],'YTickLabel', num2str([1:numcolors]'), 'YLim', [1 numcolors]); set(h, 'Ticklabels', {1 [] 3 [] 5 6}); set(h, 'Ticks', {1 3 5 6});
```

You are now setting 6 tick labels for only 4 ticks. If set the ticks to the correct values, then the auto-generated tick labels will be what you want.

Try the following:

```
h = colorbar('YTick',[1:numcolors],'YTickLabel', num2str([1:numcolors]'), 'YLim', [1 numcolors]); 
set(h, 'Ticks', {1 3 5 6});
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove some ticks with their labels, just set the `'YTick'` property of the colorbar accordingly. That is, replace your last line by something like:

```
colorbar('YTick', [1 3 5 6], 'YLim', [1 numcolors])
```

Comment: I also don't wanna show the "Ticks" corresponding to "Ticklabels" (plz see figure in question)?How can?

Comment: I add the code as follow. But it not same as my expect:   `h = colorbar('YTick',[1:numcolors],'YTickLabel', num2str([1:numcolors]'), 'YLim', [1 numcolors]);
set(h, 'Ticklabels', {1 [] 3 [] 5 6});
set(h, 'Ticks', {1  3  5 6});`